# Dynamic SQL Search & Replace Function

Tags: sql-server, function, dynamic, replace

@dmarkez asked a question yesterday, and just before I clicked the `Post Your Answer` button, he deleted the question.  I think the answer is worth sharing...  He didn't re-post the question, so I hope he doesn't mind if I re-post it so that I can share the answer with anyone else who is trying something similar:

### Original Title

MS SQL function to manipulate string

### Original Question

I need a MS SQL function that needs to determine names with prefix then combine this with actual names.

What is the best method or function to achieve this?

Prefix names: Te, De, Van, Dela, O, Mc, San, Los, etc…

Sample Input/Output Names:

```
van dam te mora te-> vandam temora te

o mara dela cruz -> omara delacruz

mc arthur white o san miguel -> mcarthur white osanmiguel

moana te aro van dolf-> moana tearo vandolf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put all the search & replace values in one table, then you can write a few lines of SQL to cycle through the S&R values to fix the names.  It's easy to add more S&R pairs to the `prefix` table, so your S&R routine is dynamic:

```
declare @prefix table (srch varchar(255), rplc varchar(255))
declare @names table (name varchar(255))

insert into @prefix
values ('te ', 'te'), ('de ', 'de'), ('van ', 'van'), ('dela ', 'dela'), ('san ', 'san'), ('o ', 'o'), ('mc ', 'mc'), ('los ', 'los')

insert into @names
values ('van dam te mora te'), ('o mara dela cruz'), ('mc arthur white o san miguel'), ('moana te aro van dolf')

while (1=1)
begin
  update n
  set    n.name = replace(n.name, p.srch, p.rplc)
  from   @names n,
         @prefix p
  where  (n.name like p.srch + '%') or (n.name like '% ' + p.srch + '%')

  if @@rowcount = 0
    break
end

select * from @names
```

Notice the `('san ', 'san')` comes before `('o ', 'o')` in the prefix table.  This is because `san` must be replaced before `o`, or `osanmiguel` will remain `osan miguel`.  The order of the S&R is therefore important.  You will need to add a clustered index to the prefix table that orders the S&R records correctly so that the S&R loop handles sub-prefixes first.